# Multiple request url mapping handler in one controller does not work in Node Express JS

Tags: node.js, express, npm

In my `server.js` file I have below url mappings:

```
app.use('/registerCourse', require('./controllers/training.controller'));
app.use('/getCourses', require('./controllers/training.controller'));
```

In `training.controller` file I have mapped below way:

```
router.post('/registerCourse', registerCourse);
router.get('/getCourses', getCourses);
```

when call `"/registerCourse","/getCourses","/getCourseDetails"` throwing error saying:

> "Cannot GET /getCourses"
>   Server.js -

```
require('rootpath')();
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var session = require('express-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var expressJwt = require('express-jwt');
var config = require('config.json');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(session({ secret: config.secret, resave: false,    saveUninitialized: true }));


app.use('/login', require('./controllers/login.controller'));

app.use('/app', require('./controllers/app.controller'));

app.use('/registerCourse', require('./controllers/training.controller'));
app.use('/getCourses', require('./controllers/training.controller'));
app.use('/getCourseDetails', require('./controllers/training.controller'));



app.get('/', function (req, res) {
return res.redirect('/app');
});


var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
console.log('Server listening at http://' + server.address().address +    ':' + server.address().port);
});
```

training.controller.js-

```
var config = require('config.json');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();  
var router = express.Router();
var trainingService = require('services/training.service');
app.use(router);  

router.post('/registerCourse', registerCourse);
router.get('/getCourses', getCourses);
router.get('/getCourseDetails', getCourseDetails);
module.exports = router;


function registerCourse(req, res) {
   console.log(" registerCourse called ()"+req.body);
   trainingService.register(req.body);

}

function getCourses(req, res) {

     trainingService.getCourses()
    .then(function (data) {
        res.json(data);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {

        res.status(400).send(err);
    });
}
function getCourseDetails(req, res) {

    console.log(req.body)
}
```

Comment: Just formatting code to make things clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Solution:*

Your route will be:

- /registerCourse
- /getCourses
- /getCourseDetails

**app.js**

```
app.use('/login', require('./controllers/login.controller'));

app.use('/app', require('./controllers/app.controller'));
app.use('/',require('./controllers/training.controller'));

/* 
app.use('/registerCourse', require('./controllers/training.controller'));
app.use('/getCourses', require('./controllers/training.controller'));
app.use('/getCourseDetails', require('./controllers/training.controller'));
-- removed
*/
```

**training.controller.js**

```
var config = require('config.json');
var express = require('express');
// var app = express();  -- removed
var router = express.Router();
var trainingService = require('services/training.service');
// app.use(router);  -- removed

router.post('/registerCourse', registerCourse);
router.get('/getCourses', getCourses);
router.get('/getCourseDetails', getCourseDetails);
module.exports = router;


function registerCourse(req, res) {
   console.log(" registerCourse called ()"+req.body);
   trainingService.register(req.body);

}

function getCourses(req, res) {

     trainingService.getCourses()
    .then(function (data) {
        res.json(data);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {

        res.status(400).send(err);
    });
}
function getCourseDetails(req, res) {

    console.log(req.body)
}
```

Comment: Hi nivesh, I have changed to                                                               app.use('/courses', require('./controllers/training.controller'))  ,  In    training.controller added                        router.post('/courses/registerCourse', registerCourse);
router.get('/courses/getCourses', getCourses);                  Still  not working

Comment: could you post your training.controller.js and your app.js

Comment: Hi nivesh,Updated Question with Code.

Comment: i have updated the answer, please check it out. There were couple of things you were doing wrong. Besides its always suggested to post your code in first place for complete understanding.

Answer (score 0):

In server.js you can use

```
app.use('/', require('./controllers/training.controller'));
app.use('/', require('./controllers/training.controller'));
app.use('/', require('./controllers/training.controller'));
```

and then try calling your

"/registerCourse","/getCourses","/getCourseDetails"